# How to do this in Laravel, subquery with join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using Laravel 4 to redo my site. The hardest part has been converting my queries to Query Builder/Eloquent format. If someone can help me get this one, the longest one, I would be super grateful!

```
SELECT zipcode, city, state, lat, lng, distance_in_mi
FROM (
SELECT zipcode, city, state, lat, lng, r, ( 3963.17 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( latpoint ) ) * COS(     RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( longpoint ) - RADIANS( lng ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( latpoint ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance_in_mi
FROM zipcode
JOIN (
SELECT $current_lat AS latpoint, $current_lng AS longpoint, 10 AS r
) AS p
WHERE lat
BETWEEN latpoint - ( r /69 ) 
AND latpoint + ( r /69 ) 
AND lng
BETWEEN longpoint - ( r / ( 69 * COS( RADIANS( latpoint ) ) ) ) 
AND longpoint + ( r / ( 69 * COS( RADIANS( latpoint ) ) ) )
) d
WHERE distance_in_mi <= r
ORDER BY distance_in_mi
```

Recent Attempt:

```
$data_object = DB::table('zipcode', function($query)
            {
        $query->select('zipcode, city, state, lat, lng, r, ( 3963.17 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( latpoint     ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( longpoint ) - RADIANS( lng ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( latpoint ) )     * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance_in_mi')
          ->from('zipcode')
          ->join('zipcode', function($query1)
            {
            $query1->select("($current_lat AS latpoint, $current_lng AS longpoint, 10 AS r) AS p")
                    ->whereBetween('lat', 'latpoint - ( r /69 )' )
                    ->whereBetween('lng', 'longpoint - ( r / ( 69 * COS( RADIANS( latpoint ) ) ) )     AND longpoint + ( r / ( 69 * COS( RADIANS( latpoint ) ) ) )' );

            })
            })
                    ->where('distance_in_mi', '<=', 'r')
                    ->orderBy('distance_in_mi')
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the join and sub select. That's what should work for you:

```
DB::table('zipcode')
->select(['zipcode','city','state','lat','lang',
    DB::raw("(3963.17*ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint))*COS(RADIANS(lat))*COS(RADIANS(longpoint)-RADIANS(lng))+SIN(RADIANS(latpoint))*SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) 
        AS distance_in_mi, $current_lat AS latpoint, $current_lng AS longpoint, 10 AS r")])
->orderBy('distance_in_mi')
->havingRaw('lat BETWEEN latpoint - (r/69)
    AND latpoint + (r/69)
    AND 
    lng BETWEEN longpoint - (r/(69*COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
    AND longpoint + (r/(69*COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
    AND distance_in_mi <= r')
->get();
```

Comment: First off, thank you very much. I tried it out, its missing a ) and a ]. Do you have a suggestion for placement?

Comment: tried moving the missing  ) ] not getting a working query still.

Comment: Of course, my bad. It's edited now. )] were missing at the end of select(), try now

Comment: I'd like to give you this one, but I am still having trouble getting it working. I noticed that in your query the definition of r was missing. I through the mySQL db up on my server: http://innovativegrower.com/zipcode.sql if that helps

Comment: Yes, first I thought r was a field and I must have pasted the code without its definition. It's there now

Comment: Something is causing an error in the query still, I'll be working on it some more tonight. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Deczo I am still held up by this query, if you can help me out more I'd be willing to pay over PayPal. Please let me know, thanks.